# Strange JavaScript function binding. Is this control flow correct?

Tags: javascript

I have the following function definitions in the same .js file (call it A.js)

```
function PParser() {
....
makeExpression = function (lexemes, index) {

    return makeNumber(lexemes, index);
}

makeDeclaration = function(lexemes, index)
{
    if (lexemes[index].TokenType != LALLPLexer.VAR) {
        throw "Expected VAR at index " + index;
    }

    if (lexemes[index + 1].TokenType != LALLPLexer.ID) {
        throw "Expected ID at index " + index + 1;
    }

    if (lexemes[index + 2].TokenType != LALLPLexer.ASSIGN) {
        throw "Expected ASSIGN at index " + index + 2;
    }

    var expressionNodeResult = makeExpression(lexemes, index + 3);

...
```

when the "makeExpression" invocation is reached, I was expecting control flow to move to the function defined just above.  However, instead, another function named "makeExpression" is called in a completely different .js file (B.js).

```
 function Controller()
{
...

this.parseToStatement = function(statementText)
{
    makeExpression = function(expressionNode)
    {
        return new IntLiteral(expressionNode.Content);
    }

    try {
        statement = parser.parseStatement(new LALLPLexer().lex(statementText));

        if (statement.NodeType == LALLPParser.DECLARATION) {

            return new Declaration(statement.Id, makeExpression(statement.Expression));
        }
    }
    catch (exception) {
        statement = new UnknownStatement(statementText);
    }

    return statement;
}
}
```

I'm not sure why.  Interestingly enough, the line "parseStatement" shown above is up the call chain from the "makeExpression" invocation.  Is this correct javascript behavior and, if so, why should I expect this behavior?  How can I get the intended behavior?

Comment: This behavior is usually a result of the order you include the scripts in your HTML file. Try changing that order around and seeing what happens.

Comment: @Elliot I added a little more context to show both these functions were defined within classes.  Is the include order still relevant?

Comment: Yes. If B is included after A the first function will be overridden. This is because functions are treated as global variables, so declaring the same function twice will override it. I'm assuming you're modifying the class you declared in file A when you declare your `makeExpression` function the second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure about this, but I think js doesn't make variables local by standard, so all those functions might be attached globally (To the `window` variable) and hence may overwrite each other.

Try adding `var` to all of those definitions (or `this.`where appropriate). Maybe that will help.

Comment: Yes, any functions not defined locally (in some kind of scope) will be attached to the `window` variable, which means that if you define a function twice, the second declaration will override the first. Defining a function with `var` outside of scope will result in the same behavior.

Comment: Yea, that was it, good call. Didn't realize var was required when defined in the scope of a constructor.

Comment: @Dejas: Ideally you'd use `this.myFunction = function() {...};` to define a function inside of a constructor.